# Symfony2, doctrine2 one-to-one undirectional relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

I have undirectional one-to-one relation in status entity for attribute $views like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TB\WallBundle\Entity\BlogsViews", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_views_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $views;
```

The problem is when i do var_dump($status)

I see:

```
  protected 'views' => 
    object(TB\WallBundle\Entity\BlogsViews)[1072]
      private 'id' => int 5
      private 'blog_views_id' => int 61477
      private 'views' => int 0
```

But i do not need this value to be fetched always... why is the "extra_lazy" fetch not working? What am i doing wrong?

BTW: I DO NOT ACCESS THE $views attribute nowhere in code.

Comment: var_dump sees your object has a field name views so it access it to print it out and when it is accessed it is fetched.

Comment: ah i see. Is there a second option to check it out?

Comment: have you tried ladybug?  https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle

Comment: no had some issues installing it(versioning...), but it's just expending library for var_dump so it will be the same. Anything else heh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine creates a proxy-object that behaves like an instance of `BlogViews`.

This is the `BlogViews` "object" you're seeing if you inspect the object with `var_dump`.

Doctrine does **not** load all the properties of that object initially. The proxy handles fetching the properties when you attempt to access them!

This means there is actually no database-query as long as you don't try to access the lazy loading object/collection.

Keep in mind that `var_dump` **does** access these properties to show them to you!

This is expected behavior and doesn't mean the relation is *not* lazy-fetched.

I hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: yes it is. But i have question if i can somehow check to be sure the objects are not really loaded? + my query for fetching statuses has been modified because of one to one relationship that i have added. There is new left join for this blogs_views. Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: Doctrine needs that join to know what object it should create as the proxy. You can force a partial load with `$query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true)` ... Further information about this problem can be found in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/fkIaKxifDqc). Quotes: "*joins on to-one associations are relatively cheap*", "*lazy-loading is simply not always possible, technically*" - ask yourself wether you really need that deep optimization here and if its worth the effort :)

Comment: yea the left join is super cheap of course i am not worried about it. But i would like to optimalize memory that's why i added fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" to it. So i guess i will leave it like that and i will believe the objects are just proxy untill i access them? :) Thank you for your time nifr.

Comment: Anytime @Trki - glad i could help. Happy coding ... or should I say "*Bonne Chance*" ? I have an eye on your project ;)

Comment: ouuuuu i remember now! hh. We have spoke together like 8months ago or so did not we? :) And don't say anytime if you don't mean it because currently i am looking for some mentor :) :D

Comment: Why have you stop communicate with me after i told you my idea? Did something happen?